# Accessing resource file in jar

Tags: java, hibernate

I am making a maven java project in eclipse. Now I am required to make a executable jar by command line by maven.
While my code is executing resource file, it works fine but in some scenario it does not work.
My code structure is as follow :

Directory Structure:

```
src/main/java: A.java
src/main/resources: file1.properties
```

```
class A {
    private static final String TEMPLATE_LOCATION= "src/main/resources/";

    public static void main() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(TEMPLATE_LOCATION + "file1.properties"));
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I am making jar file by:

```
mvn package
```

jar file structure:

```
target/jarFileName.jar  
target/classes:  
com/A.class  
file1.properties
```

contents in jar:

```
com/A.class  
file1.properties
```

Command to execute:

```
cd myProjectRootDirectory
java -jar target/jarFileName.jar
```

It works fine.
But when I execute from target folder like:

```
cd target
java -jar jarFileName.jar
```

does not work.

```
Error: src/main/resources/file1.properties not found.
```

I changed code by

```
props.load(new props.load(FileInputStream(A.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file1.properties").getPath())));
```

Then also does not work.
But in eclipse it works fine.

Any can suggest me, where i am doing mistake?

Comment: 1- `src` (or `main/...`) is not likely to exist once your application is compiled, especially when compiled into a `Jar`. 2- You should be access resources of this nature using `Class#getResource`, for example `A.class.getResource("file1.properties")` or `A.class.getResource("/file1.properties")` ... I think the first one works in this example, but I can never remember...I also don't think `resources` itself is included with the application, but it's contents is

Comment: The easiest way would probably be this: `props.load(new InputStreamReader(A.class.getResourceAsStream("/file1.properties")));`

Comment: yes we have to use A.class.getResourceAsStream("/file1.properties"), because in jar file, file contents goes. thanks but A.class.getResource("file1.properties") or A.class.getResource("/file1.properties") will not work for scenario i have mentioned. I checked this. My problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use getResourceAsStream function and you already specified the resource folder main/resources at your pom don't use this at your implementatition. This function will get any file in the classpath. FileInputStream will search the file as starting from the current working directory. So it is not safe(wrong use) when you reading the file in the jar file.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)

public static Properties loadFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = null;


    inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);


    props.load(inputStream);

    return props;
}
```

Comment: we have to use A.class.getResourceAsStream("/file1.properties") please check my comments. thanks, solved